# PHP not comparing "#"

Tags: php, ajax, text, server

I have a simple script where I enter some text on my search bar and PHP echo the first character from the text.

My code:

```php
$data = strval($_GET['u']);
$ss = substr($data, 0,1);

if ($ss == "@") {
    echo("@");
} else if ($ss == "#")  {
    echo("htttt");
} else {
    echo($ss);
}
```

Here everything is working fine but the # is neither being compared nor being echo. It just shows blank. I tried to convert it into a string using strval() but it's not working too! What should I do?

my ajax call from jquery:

```
$("#search").on('input', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var sv = $("#search").val();
            $.get('phpscripts/short/searchdata.php?u='+sv, function(data) {
                $("#s-h").text(data);
            });

});
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `$_GET['u']`. The code is correct.

Comment: No problem in the code. check printing `$data`

Comment: if i put a random string with `#` "_httt_" will output.

Comment: if's value is #hii(anything that starts from #) I do not get any echo.

Comment: Is `#` not a reserved character in a querystring? In other words it is not getting passed to you because PHP is treating it as a delimiter?

Comment: the anchor tag is never sended as part of the http request in any browser

Comment: What is the solution? I need to know if the first letter is # or not. Thanks :) @Bacca001

Comment: You have to encode it.. try with yourvar=%23hiiii

Comment: Should I encode on the client side? How?

Comment: # is a reserved character.... browsers interpret this as elementid rather than just # so it won't work use another character and avoid url encodable characters

Comment: Can you post the part of code where you call the .php file? @sandesh

Comment: @KevinGales this is what I am looking for. I have a # system to categorize the content types. Isn't there any way to pass the hashtag?

Comment: @Bacca001 I have updated the question. Have a look at it.

Comment: do url encode decode as suggested by @Bacca001

Comment: How can I encode it on client-side?

Comment: Try with `var sv = encodeURIComponent($("#search").val());` @sandesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `#` is a *fragment* that is not sent to the server and also the part coming after it. So you will never get *#* by `$_GET['u']`, until you decode it.
Since the *UPDATE* you can control the querystring. So encode query in Client side (*JS*). Then decode it in Server side (*PHP*) back.
**JS*:*

```js
encodeURIComponent("#"); // %23
```

**PHP*:*

```php
urldecode('%23'); // #
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that `$ss` is `#`, then you could try the following:

```php
if(strcmp($ss, "#") == 0) 
{
    echo("htttt");
}
```

If your `$ss` variable is not `#`, then your statement will be false.
Since strings can be seen as an array of characters and if the first character is actually `#`, you could try doing

```php
$ss == $data[0];
```

Comment: If you `echo($ss)` before the if statements, what do you get?

Comment: if there is # I get nothing as output.

Comment: The $_GET is ignoring #.